# Makeindex rejection

Tags: nomenclature, makeindex

I tried finding the solution on line, and could not find any suitable answer to my question.

My aim is to make a nomenclature. In order to do this, I need to perform the operation `makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls`.
However, I seem to only get rejections. (0 entries accepted, 2 rejected).

I'm having trouble interpreting the log file, so here it is.

```
This is makeindex, version 2.15 [MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit] (kpathsea + Thai support).
Scanning style file C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist.......
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 70):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_prefix.
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 71):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_suffix.
** Input style error (file = C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/makeindex/nomencl/nomencl.ist, line = 72):
   -- Unknown specifier lethead_flag.
...done (10 attributes redefined, 3 ignored).
Scanning input file Slutrapport.nlo...
!! Input index error (file = Slutrapport.nlo, line = 1):
   -- Illegal page number -100.
!! Input index error (file = Slutrapport.nlo, line = 2):
   -- Illegal page number -100.
done (0 entries accepted, 2 rejected).
Nothing written in Slutrapport.nls.
Transcript written in Slutrapport.ilg.
```

Am I missing something fundamental or why is it rejecting?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you've included the whole nomenclature into a separated file and you're calling it to the main file with the command `\input{filename.tex}`.

I had the same problem with the nomenclature rejection but I read something has to be written before the nomenclature into the `nlo` file in order to generate an output. I just placed the nomenclature inputs after using an equation and the problem was solved.

Perhaps it's not your case, but if it is give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I encoutered the same problem today while using TexStudio. After repeatedly generating the empty .nls file due to rejections. The solution was to mark the glossary section within TexStudio.

[image: Tool Section TexStudio]

A single click at Glossary and Index fixed the issue after using

> makeindex filename.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o filename.nls